# reading content of a file from server then sending it to client through socket C#

Tags: sockets, file-io, streamreader, streamwriter

i am trying here to send the content of a text file by the server and send it to the client

this is the server

```
Socket server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                 SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        IPEndPoint localEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 9050);
        server.Bind(localEP);
        server.Listen(10);
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for Client...");
        Socket client = server.Accept();
        IPAddress clientAddress = ((IPEndPoint)client.RemoteEndPoint).Address;
        Console.WriteLine("Got connection from " + clientAddress);

    NetworkStream stream = new NetworkStream(client); 
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);


    writer.WriteLine("Welcome to my test server");
    writer.Flush();
    string line = null;
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()).Length != 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("loooking for this file:" + line);
        System.IO.FileInfo fi = new System.IO.FileInfo(line);
        Console.WriteLine("Found");
        writer.WriteLine("File Size: " + fi.Length + "\nContent:");
        StreamReader tr = new StreamReader(line);
        string s = null;
        //string b = "";
    while((s= tr.ReadLine()).Length != 0)
        {
            writer.WriteLine(tr.ReadLine());
            writer.Flush();
        }

        tr.Close();

    }
    client.Close(); server.Close();
```

the part of the client where it reads from the server is this

```
String line = null;
        line = textBox3.Text;
        writer.WriteLine(line);   // Send line to Server
        writer.Flush();
        string s = null;
        // Read line from server, then echo on the screen 
        while((s= reader.ReadLine()).Length != 0)
        {
            textBox4.Text += reader.ReadLine() + "\r\n\r\n";
        }
```

when i run the code, no errors at all, but the client get stuck, and when i stop the server, the content of the file will show,,, BTW, its a GUI application

Answer (score 0):

while ((s = reader.ReadLine()) != null) {
  textBox4.Text += s;
}

Comment: mmm, still the same problem, it doesnt show what it reads untill i stop the server

Answer (score 0):

[Sample code for StreamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline.aspx) uses the construct below to detect end of stream.  Also - do you really want to read two lines in that loop?

```
while (reader.Peek() >= 0) 
{
    s= reader.ReadLine();
    textBox4.Text += s + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;
}
```

Comment: sorry, this didnt help :S... actually what am trying to do is i want to read a text file by the server and i want to send it to the client, so am reading line by line and send it to the server, and i tried to read the whole file and send it, both ways are working, but i should stop the server so the client application display the content :S

Comment: @Nadeem - I would try this using two different `NetworkStream`s on the server - one for reading and the other for writing.  Same on the client if you have only a single one there.

Comment: i have tried to do two networkstreams, but its not working, still the clien freeze, and when i stop the server, its working

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that this is a GUI app? If so, on which thread are you doing the reading? If you are doing the read on the main thread, then the application messageloop will be frozen and nothing will show up until you stop the other side and kill the connection.

Comment: for my gui , am not using any threads, and i did the same thing but i used console applicatoin, i used reader.readtoend(), the client also freezes, and when i killed the server, it showed me the whole text in the console..  console.write(reader.readtoend());